# Find and replace a full line in HTML file

Tags: text, replace, batch-processing

I need to edit about 600 HTML files, each of which has a line in the following format:

```
John Doe<div class="author"><b>Added: </b>July 8, 2006</div>
```

The name and the date are going to be different in every document.  I need to remove this line from all the documents.

What is the fastest way to do this, using Windows?

Answer (score 2):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR %%f IN (*.html) DO (
 FINDSTR /v /r /c:"^.*<div class=\"author\"><b>Added: </b>.*</div>$" "%%f" >"%%~nf.new"
 FC "%%f" "%%~nf.new"
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Should see this problem off.

The `fc` line is only for verification - it should show the differences between the `.html` file and the `.new` file. Can be dropped once verified.

Comment: @Knocks X Copy paste the script Magoo wrote and save it in a file with a .bat extension.

Comment: I had already modified the files by the time your answer was posted, so I couldn't test your script, but I upvoted it anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the name of the files into a python script like this

```
# Run as script.py *.html
import fileinput, sys
for line in fileinput.input(inplace=1):
    if '<div class="author"><b>Added: </b>' not in line:
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Note that the files will be modified without backup, so keep a backup before running the command.

Comment: Is it possible to do this from Windows?

Comment: Yes, if you have Python installed. Else you can use @Magoo 's solution.

Answer (score 0):

I ended using the 'Replace in files' function in Notepad++ with the following regular expression

> `^.*Added.*$`